# Svn revert all properties changes

Tags: svn

I have a svn working copy which I attempted to reverse merge a couple of recent revisions into. I cancelled the merge before it completed as I changed my mind. Now my working copy has a couple of thousand "changes" from updates to the ancestry related properties on most of the files. I have about 10 files with real code changes mixed in which I don't want to have to seperate out by hand.

Is there a way for me to revert all of the property changes without affecting the content changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that Tortoise SVN can do this really nicely. In the commit dialog you can sort the "modified" files by "text status" or "properties status". I simply sorted by text status and then reverted all the "modified" files which had "normal" "text status".

Comment: This works for revert too (and I imagine any other Tortoise command). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 33):

```
svn revert `svn status | grep '^ M' | sed 's/^ M \+//g'`
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, I forgot to replace my bash alias :)

Comment: You should use '^ M' instead of ' M'. Also, what about files like 'MM' with relevant text changes but propertie changes to discard?

Answer (score 22):

If you use the revert option `--depth empty`, you'll revert changes only to paths explicitly specified on the command line and not recursively.  So if those changes are property changes, that will be the only thing you revert.

Example: if you have the directory `foo` with unwanted property changes, but its content has modifications, the following will revert the property changes, but keep the modifications of its content:

```
$ svn revert --depth empty foo
```

as is demonstrated here:

```
$ svn status foo
 M      foo
M       foo/bar
$ svn revert --depth empty foo
$ svn status foo
M       foo/bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Revert all property changes with PowerShell.

```
> @(svn status) -match '^ M' | `
>>> % { ($_ -split 'M\s+')[1] } | `
>>> % { svn revert --depth empty $_ }
```

Credit to **Jerome Jaglale** and **TheJuice** for the general approach.

Note the backtick `` ` `` symbol indicates a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your changes and then revert the property changes from that revision:

svn merge -c -REV -depth empty

where REV is the revision where you want to revert the property changes

Answer (score -4):

I would just copy/backup the 10 files with the real code change somewhere else, and just `svn revert -R` the whole project, then copy back the 10 files.