# Recursively ignoring files in the entire source tree in subversion without removing existing ignore properties

Tags: svn, svnignore

I wish to add a line to my svn:ignore for, say, the pattern "*.bak".

I'd like this to be done recursively for the whole tree.  I can do this as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230700/recursively-ignoring-files-in-the-entire-source-tree-in-subversion):

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*.bak' . --recursive
```

However I found that this method will remove any existing ignore rules I have.

Is there some way I can recursively add a new line to the svn:ignore property without removing what is there already?

Many of my subdirectories already have multiple ignore patterns, and I don't want all subdirectories to have the same ignore patters.  I'd just like to add a new pattern to every directory.

I hope that is all clear.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` command:

```
    find . -name "*.bak" \
       -execdir bash -c 'svn -q propset svn:ignore -F <((svn propget svn:ignore; basename "{}") | sort -u) .' \;
```

I use `sort -u` for consistency and uniqueness.

Comment: This will only add the ignore pattern on the directories where a *.bak file already exists so you may have to re-run the command in the future as new *.bak files are added in other directories. What if you wanted to properly set it up once and for all?

Comment: You're perfectly right and the process CAN'T be made cleanly before svn 1.8 (that's why I always considered subversion as inferior by design). However, you can use the inherated properties mecanism.(http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#iprops)

Answer (score 0):

To ignore more than one 'type' or 'pattern' you need to supply a file

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F patterns.txt
```

So, to do what you want you'll need to take it one step further and get the prop list, append to it with a temporary file, etc.

Either that or you could write a web client that talks directly to the SVN/Dav server, gets the props and sets them.

Comment: My problem is that many of my sub directories already have multiple ignore patterns set.  I do not want every directory to have the same ignore patters, I just wish to add a new ignore pattern to the existing ones in each directory.

Comment: Yep. You'll need to write a script that recurses the directories, gets a list of the current ignores, puts it into a tmp file, append your new ignore and then apply it using -F. Not the easiest solution, but I can't find any better way.

Answer (score 0):

`svn propedit` **edit** properties

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am looking for something which will recursively set a property on every folder in the tree.  As I understand it that will only work on one folder - is that right?

Comment: 1. `svn pg svn:ignore . -R` will give you all subdirs with svn:ignore defined 2. `svn pg svn:ignore <dir> > file` save all old patterns 3. `echo <somedata> >> file` add new  4. `propset -F` define new-set

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by `juj` works but will only add the ignore patterns for the directories where such a file already exists so you may have to re-run the script in the future. Also, you get the specific file name in the `svn:ignore` property (as opposed to the pattern).

An alternative solution that doesn't have the above issues is provided in my following answer:
[unix.stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108239/24044).