# SVN ignore like .gitignore

Tags: svn, svnignore

In [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), if I have a project with lots of projects inside, let's suppose, a lot of Java projects, I can just create a `.gitignore` file in the root and it will "be respected" in the entire repository.

How can I do this for an SVN project?

For example, how can I make an "svn ignore" setup (via cmd line) for a `.gitignore` like the following?

```
*.class
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
target/
.classpath
.settings/
.project
.metadata
bin/
```

The most important part of the question: How can I make it work to new folders inside the root? Example:

I ran `svn propset svn:ignore "*.class" . -R` in my root and commit. Ok:

```
root
- folder1/
-- *.class (ignored)
-- other files (ok)
- folder2/
-- *.class (ignored)
-- other files (ok)
```

Now, I create folder 3. The previous `svn:ignore` settings will not apply, right? Is there a way to make it so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursively ignoring files in the entire source tree in subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230700/recursively-ignoring-files-in-the-entire-source-tree-in-subversion)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use `svn:ignore`. You generally need to tell SVN to apply special properties to the files:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.jpg" .
```

(Note the dot at the end of the command.)

For multiple files you can add a newline character.

Type exactly like here with line breaks:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "file1
file2
file3" dir1
```

Check that the files are ignored:

```
svn status --no-ignore
```

Then commit the code.

And yes, many duplicate questions are already available.

You can refer my favorite [svn cheatguide](http://web.archive.org/web/20121021221547/http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/svn/).

You can create a file, `svn-ignore.txt`, with your ignored files and directories:

```
*.class
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
 target/
.classpath
.settings/
.project
.metadata
 bin/
```

Now try the following:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -RF /root/svn-ignore.txt . [dot for current dir]
```

`-R` is for recursive.

Comment: How would you handle multi-level directories eg `app/code/core`

Comment: The recursive parameter "-R" should handle any depth of directories

Comment: From the cheatsheet: ```Edit a dir's ignores:
 $ svn propedit svn:ignore your_dir_name```

Comment: which file does svn propset svn:ignore modify ? i need to know because I would like to actually check it in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087166/which-file-does-svnignore-modify

Comment: 1) does this mean that one need to set the ignore files at every commit or only once and this will apply for the workflow from now on? 
2) how can one undo the ignoring of a file?

Comment: There is only one problem I have with `svn propset`.

When I use `.gitignore` I can use it to avoid modifying certain files *and* choose not to add the ignore file to the git repo itself by never staging it.

 `svn propset` values will go into the svn repo on the next commit (if you dont commit specific files) and affect everybody.

Comment: What's the context here? Do you type this in the CLI? so you have to specify what you want to ignore every friggin time? How terribly short-sighted SVN is designed, after all these years.

Comment: A leading space and trailing slash in folder names in `svn-ignore.txt` above, such as  ` target/`, needed to be removed in my environment. Windows 10, TortoiseSVN 1.12.0.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I am doing to emulate `.svnignore`.

Create a wrapper for `svn` called `~/bin/svn`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
commit|status|apply-ignore)
    if test -f .svnignore ; then
        echo "Apply .svnignore: $(/usr/bin/svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .)"
    fi
    ;;
esac
case "$1" in
apply-ignore) ;;
*) exec /usr/bin/svn "$@" ;;
esac
```

Then add `~/bin` to your path before `/usr/bin`

```sh
PATH=~/bin:$PATH ; export PATH
```

It applies `.svnignore` on `commit` and `status` commands, and can also manually apply using `svn apply-ignore`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TortoiseSVN as many do, there's an easy way to ignore files. Right you can right anywhere in Windows Explorer to bring up the TortoiseSVN Menu and select **Settings**, in the *General* tab click the **Edit** button under the section labeled *Subversion*. It will launch *Notepad*. or default text editor, with file named *config*.

Locate a line with **global-ignores** and commented out with # in the file:

```
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output, and
### while importing or adding files and directories.
### '*' matches leading dots, e.g. '*.rej' matches '.foo.rej'.
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__
#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db
```

Uncomment the line and add or replace the file patterns with the files you want to ignore and save the file.

```
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__
    #   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem a slightly different way. This will only work if you're using a Bash shell and have Perl installed, but that's pretty much every Mac and Linux machine.

Add the following to your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files:

```
alias _ss="svn status | egrep -v '`cat .svnignore|perl -p -e 's/\n/|/'`'"
```

Don't forget to either restart your terminal or do:

```
source ~/.bashrc
(or .bash_profile if that's what you used)
```

Now create a file called **.svnignore**, and put it in the directory where your repository is checked out.

```
files/to/ignore
another/file
tmp
node_modules
```

Now when you run

```
_ss
```

in the root directory of your working copy, it will read the .svnignore file and ignore anything in it.

I version the .svnignore file the same way I would version a .gitignore file.

**NOTE:** This only affects the **svn status** command, and it won't prevent you from adding/committing ignored files.

Comment: There's no need for such kind of hacks while there's a proper way to do this.

Comment: @dimir Maybe you want to use git and svn the same way. For example GitHub has also an svn bridge.