# Which file does svn:ignore modify?

Tags: svn, gitignore, ignore, svnignore

I would like to know which file `svn propset svn:ignore` modifies (equivalent to `.gitignore`) so that I can actually commit that file to the repo.

E.g. I am working with `Java` and `Maven`, which creates a directory named "target", which I am ignoring. `svn propset svn:ignore target .` does work but I don't know which settings file is modifies by that command so that I propagate the change to my team.

<sub>**RELATED:** [SVN ignore like .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298668/svn-ignore-like-gitignore)</sub>

Comment: It does not modify a versioned file, it is stored internally in .svn file (or files depending on SVN version). This will be propagated to the team, the same way you can propagate new files or deletion which are also stored in the .svn file(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn:ignore` property is stored together with other properties inside the `.svn` folder. It will be stored in the repository automatically after your next commit. If you want to commit only `svn:ignore` change without commiting other "normal" files you can try:

```
svn commit --depth=empty .
```

The value of `svn:ignore` can be checked with `svn propget svn:ignore`.

Comment: how can I see that `svn:ignore` has changed ?

Comment: you can check the value of `svn:ignore` with `svn propget svn:ignore`

Comment: however, will that tell me whether the property set has changed relative to the repo ?

Comment: `svn propget svn:ignore` checks the value in your local working copy. If you want to check the value of `svn:ignore` in the repository you can try `svn propget svn:ignore URL`, where URL is the location of your remote repository.