# Ignoring dir and sub dirs when commiting

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I have script which generates a lot of directories inside each directory like:

```
/home/content/logs/a
/home/content/logs/a/b
/home/content/logs/a/b/c
```

etc.
My main repo dir is **/home**.

I want to ignore /home/content/logs directory and the subdirectories of logs.

I tried command like:

> svn propset svn:ignore content/logs .

but it didn't work and when I'm commiting file, directory logs and subdirectories are still visible...
I did research in stackoverflow but anywhere is the same solution.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Hope anyone will help me, Regards

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230700/recursively-ignoring-files-in-the-entire-source-tree-in-subversion) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @roelofs unfortunately not, but thanks. I have tried 'svn propset svn:ignore "*" content/logs --recursive --force' but I'm getting: "svn: Directory 'content/logs/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing"

Comment: Have you tried something like `svn propset svn:ignore "logs/*" ./content --recursive` ?

Comment: @roelofs yeah, still the sam error

Comment: Perhaps you can try adding an empty /logs to your repository - that would add the required .svn directory, but then just not commit anything going forward?

Comment: @roelofs I'm sure that i have all files and dirs. I dont know what is going on...

Comment: @roelofs Can you test this solution on your repo?

Comment: I don't have a live one on my current machine.  The .svn directory is where it stores its information, and it appears the /logs directory does not have one, from that error message?  Is logs currently part of your repo?

Comment: @roelofs however, thanks for help. I will think about it...

Comment: I may misunderstood something, but if you want to ignore the logs directory altogether shouldn't be enough with `svn propset svn:ignore "logs" ./content`?